# Python solve pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
1 
2    1 
4    2    1 
8    4    2    1 
16   8    4    2    1 
32   16   8    4    2    1 
64   32   16   8    4    2    1 
128  64   32   16   8    4    2   1
```

I try this please help me to solve this pattern what I have to change:

```
rows = 9
for i in range(1, rows):
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print("")
```

Comment: You should start by fixing your syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another pythonic way of doing it:

```py
def pow_2_triangle(rows):
    pows = [f"{str(2**i):4}" for i in range(rows)]
    for i in range(rows):
        print(" ".join(reversed(pows[:i+1])))
```

```
>>> pow_2_triangle(9)
1
2    1
4    2    1
8    4    2    1
16   8    4    2    1
32   16   8    4    2    1
64   32   16   8    4    2    1
128  64   32   16   8    4    2    1
256  128  64   32   16   8    4    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the following function. In order to create the pattern you shared, you need to specify 8 rows:

```
def createPattern(numberOfRows):
    for i in range (0, numberOfRows):
        string = ""
        for j in range (i, -1, -1):
            string += str(2**j) +"\t"
        print (string)

numberOfRows = int(input("Please tell me how many rows you would like"))

createPattern(numberOfRows)
```

Hope you find it useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

here, understand what loop is doing

```
rows = 9
for i in range(1, rows):
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(2**(j-1), end=' ')
    print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but you can definitely give this a try

```
print(1)
rows = 9
test_=[1]

for i in range(1, rows):
    
    test1=test_[0]*2
    test_.insert(0,test1)
    test2=[str(x) for x in test_]
    print(' '.join(test2)
```